VScode - Go To Definition is never found for HTML and external JS files (included screenshots)
I don't even know if this is normal behaviour or it is broken.
But similar to how "Go To Definition" works between CSS and HTML files, where you're taken to the class or id referenced in HTML or CSS, it works perfectly both ways.
Now, with external JS files in my HTML this does not work. "Go To Definition" from HTML does not find the referenced function in my .JS file. Even "Find All References" yields "No Results"
Although if the script is embedded into HTML with script tags, then Go To Definition works as well as Find All References. But most of my javscript files are externally linked.
Here are some screenshots for clarity.
I've spent 2 hours like a crazed-woman trying to get to the bottom of this, so i would really really love some clarification.




That might be happening because the vs-code is unable to distinguish between .html file and .js file.
I would suggest better stop wasting your time on useless thing and learn proper convention(Best Practice) like:

Always name function like execNew rather than ExecNew 1st letter lowerCase which might make someone confuse and people mistake it for constructor function
If you are defining function in Javascript target button in Javascript and addEventListener to it.

index.html
<body>

 <button class="btn">Click me and see Magic</button>

 <script src="./basic.js"></script> <!-- Make sure you target btn after its rendered -->
</body>

external js file (basic.js)
const btn = document.querySelector(".btn");

btn.addEventListener("click", printSomething);

function printSomething() {
  console.log("Hello sir");
}


Thank you for your advice. Although this code which i posted, is simply a demo code which i wrote to demonstrate my issue as i cannot post my entire project files here.
My issue is not really "useless thing" because when you have 100's of functions and classes, it becomes neccesary to have features like Go To Definition. That being said, my issue is still not solved.
If someone can help, i would love that.

Vscode is not smart enough to check between .html and .js file for the referencing. Even I use this feature and its unable to distinguish and I even have faces this problem serveral time when finding the type and function source between ts and js file. I have to explicitly find the code. Its just they dont provide powerful referencing
But yeh If you want to make it good referencing make sure the file type is same then only you can benefit from this
